# Search for a key or value in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hello I have a topicA in Kafka and i stored a message with `key =name` and `value=John` .Is there a way query for the specific value or key ?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible in Kafka.

Kafka ist not a key-value storage but more an "append-only" log. It uses an index called `offset` which you can use to consume a particular message. However, the offset is not related to the content of the data and you need to know it in advance.

The alternative is to consume all messages in a topic and then filter out the one you are interested. But that will be quite inefficient and is probably not what you were looking for.

Comment: So if I want to store in Kafka different objects like Rooms and Stores, I have to create 2 topics with the names TopicRoom and TopicStore. After I will store in each specific partition 0 for Room1,partition 1 for Room2 etc. and respectively for TopicStore and If I want Information for Room2 should I fetch the newest offset and after filter the value for what I want?

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution. Not sure about the amount of data that will reside in each of the partitions in the end but you can definitely use topics and partitions to "bucket" your data.